# gem install fails with "ruby: invalid option -H (-h will show valid options) (RuntimeError)"

Tags: ruby, rubygems, installation, rvm, native

running gem install ffi on OSX Mountain lion yields the following error.

```
gem install ffi
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing ffi:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /beweiche.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p374/bin/ruby extconf.rb
/beweiche.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p374/bin/ruby: invalid option -H  (-h will show valid options) (RuntimeError)


Gem files will remain installed in /beweiche.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374@hugo/gems/ffi-1.8.1 for inspection.
```

This happens with any native extension.
Using the system ruby (1.8.7) I can install gems with native extensions. It even worked with 1.9.3. but after doing a "gem update installed", I got stuck.

installed gems on my machine:

```
bundler (1.2.3)
coderay (1.0.9)
diff-lcs (1.2.4)
graph (2.5.2)
method_source (0.8.1)
pry (0.9.12.1)
rake (10.0.3)
rspec (2.13.0)
rspec-core (2.13.1)
rspec-expectations (2.13.0)
rspec-mocks (2.13.1)
rubygems-bundler (1.1.0)
rvm (1.11.3.6)
slop (3.4.4)
```

It seems to be a stupid typo somewhere but I cannot find where.

Any hint is highly appreciated.

meanwhile, I have installed ruby 2.0.0-rc1 in my rvm. With this setting, I could install gems with native extensions. I upgraded the gems to the same versions in 1.9.3  as they are in 2.0.0 but the problem is still there.

Comment: is `/beweiche.rvm` correct?

Comment: yes, this is correct. It is soft linked to /Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/beweiche/.rvm/ in order to avoid spaces in the path.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use `homebrew`?  If so, try installing ffi via `brew install libffi` prior to running `bundle`.

Why did you run `gem update installed`?  You should just let Bundler handle the updates for you: `bundle` or `bundle update gem_xyz`.  If you want to add a new gem, simply add it to the Gemfile.

I am assuming that when you updated all your gems, one of them was updated to depend on FFI.  You can verify this by searching for `ffi` in `Gemfile.lock`.  Once you see which gem depends on it, you an decide whether to fix that gem to an earlier version within your Gemfile, and get rid of the dependency altogether, or move forward with lib installation.

Comment: I never managed to make homebrew work on my machine. I will try again, and if it does not work, I'll open aonother question here. But thanks for the hint with bundler.